# Generating Finite Groups By Random Premultiplication With Generators

Tags: probability, combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with identity $e$ and $S$ be a set which generates $G$. Is it always possible to define a procedure of the form:

1. Start with $x=e$.
2. With probability $p_1$, replace $x$ with $s_1x$.
3. With probability $p_2$, replace $x$ with $s_2x$.

and so on with $p_i \in [0,1]$ and $s_i\in S$ such that the value of $x$ is uniformly distributed by the end of the process. That is, define a sequence of random variables as:
$$X_0=e$$
$$P(X_n=s_nX_{n-1})=p_n$$
 $$P(X_n=X_{n-1})=1-p_n$$
such that, for some $n$, we have that $X_n$ is a uniform distribution over $G$?

---

I would assume that *constructing* such sequences is not a tractable problem (except numerically), but proving existence might be easier. In particular, consider the case of a one element $S=\{s\}$. If we continually multiply by $s$ with probability $\frac{1}2$, we can prove (for instance, by the contraction mapping theorem) that for $g\in G$: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}P(X_n=g)=\frac{1}{|G|}.$$
And choosing some sufficiently large $n$, we would expect to be able to "jigger" (to use the technical term) the $p_i$ to make things exactly right, as there would be arbitrarily many degrees of freedom available to adjust a fixed set of probabilities an arbitrarily small distance to the goal. One can likely repeat the same argument for $S$ with multiple elements by considering that multiplying by a single element $s$ enough should be able to make $x$ and $sx$ equally likely - and if we repeat this process enough, perhaps we can solve the general case. I'm fairly sure that algebraic solutions can always yield $p_i$ for appropriate choice of $s_i$, but, problematically, may not respect the constraint that $p_i\in [0,1]$.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is impossible unless under very special conditions, probably something like $S \cup {e} = G$. My intuitive reason is that if the Markov process has an invertible matrix, then the stable state cannot be reached from any other state. (But no I didn't try to prove my claim.)

Comment: @user21820 That's a very good point - to make the transition matrix non-invertible, we would need to multiply by an element of order 2 with probability $\frac{1}2$ at some point (So if $S$ contains no such elements, the answer is negative)

Comment: Oh, correction, of *even* order (with probability $\frac{1}2$)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  This cannot be done with the cyclic group of order $3$.

Let $G = \mathbb{Z}/3$ with generator $1$, and consider the effect of any one step of the given process.  If the probability distribution before the step is $(P_0,P_1,P_2)$ and the step adds $1$ with probability $p$, then the probability distribution after the step is
$$
(P_0',P_1',P_2') \;=\; \bigl((1-p)P_0+pP_2,\;(1-p)P_1+pP_0,\;(1-p)P_2+p P_1\bigr)
$$
Now suppose $(P_0',P_1',P_2') = (1/3,1/3,1/3)$.  This gives us three linear equations
$$
(1-p)P_0+pP_2=1/3,\quad (1-p)P_1+pP_0=1/3,\quad (1-p)P_2+pP_1 = 1/3,
$$
and it is easy to check that the only solution is $P_0=P_1=P_2=1/3$, for any real value of $p$.

Thus, it is impossible to arrive at the uniform distribution unless you are already there, so you cannot arrive at a uniform distribution in a finite number of steps.